# I trying authenticate a user using passport.js but it gives me a error **the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)**

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

When i register a user it successfully saved into database but when i authenticate a user it gives me **400 (Bad Request) error**

In this i am using **passport.js, passport-local, passport-local-mongoose** for authentication

Here is my code:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/logindb", {useNewUrlParser: true});
    
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String
});
    
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);        
    
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
```

code for serializeUser and deserializeUser:

```
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());    
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

Here is my code for register a user and authenticate the user:

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res){
    
        User.register({username: req.body.email}, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {console.log(err); res.redirect('/'); }
            else{
                passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function(){
                    res.redirect('/home')
                })
                res.redirect('login')
            }
            
        });
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got the sintex wrong.
Try this instaed:

```
passport.authenticate('local'), function (req, res){
  res.redirect('/home')
})
```